# Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cArr) in Crystal

Tags: c#, crystal-lang

I'm converting some C# code into Crystal code for a project: my goal is to convert a string into an ASCII Byte array.

#### C# code

The C# code is the following:

```
string expression = "nYrXa@9Q\x00bf1&hCWM\\9(731Bp?t42=!k3.";
char[] cArr = expression.ToCharArray();
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cArr);
```

Which gives:

```
{byte[32]} = 110, 89, 114, 88, 97, 64, 57, 81, 63, 49, 38, 104, 67, 87, 77, 92, 57, 40, 55, 51, 49, 66, 112, 63, 116, 52, 50, 61, 33, 107, 51, 46
```

#### Crystal implementation

```
temp = "nYrXa@9Q\x00bf1&hCWM\\9(731Bp?t42=!k3."
byteDecKey = temp.to_slice
array = [] of UInt8
temp.each_char do |char|
    array << char.bytes[0] unless !char.ascii?
end

puts "EachChrKey: #{array}"
puts "ByteDecKey: #{byteDecKey}"
```

Result:

```
EachChrKey:      [110, 89, 114, 88, 97, 64, 57, 81, 120, 48, 48, 98, 102, 49, 38, 104, 67, 87, 77, 92, 57, 40, 55, 51, 49, 66, 112, 63, 116, 52, 50, 61, 33, 107, 51, 46]
ByteDecKey: Bytes[110, 89, 114, 88, 97, 64, 57, 81, 120, 48, 48, 98, 102, 49, 38, 104, 67, 87, 77, 92, 57, 40, 55, 51, 49, 66, 112, 63, 116, 52, 50, 61, 33, 107, 51, 46]
C Sharp   : Bytes[110, 89, 114, 88, 97, 64, 57, 81, 63, 49, 38, 104, 67, 87, 77, 92, 57, 40, 55, 51, 49, 66, 112, 63, 116, 52, 50, 61, 33, 107, 51, 46]
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In your C# code, `\x00bf` is being interpreted as an escape code representing the byte `0xbf`, whereas in crystal, strings do not support `\x` escape codes as strings can contain only valid unicode. Therefore the contents of the string contain the characters `x00bf` instead of the signal byte `0xbf`. `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` seems to replace the unknown byte `0xbf` with `?`.

I'd suggest using `Slice(UInt8)` for holding binary data, and using some encoding method such as base64 to transport the data if it's required as a string. Strings are meant to contain only valid unicode, not arbitrary data.

Comment: Crystal appears to support escape codes now, `"\x04\x00"` stands for `Bytes[4, 0]`. See https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.32.1/String.html#non-utf-8-valid-strings